# convert .exe file to .com file with exe2bin in DOS system

Tags: assembly, exe, typeconverter

The environment is MS-DOS system.
I have a simple h.asm code for hello world output using dos 9# call

```
.386
DATA    SEGMENT USE16
MSG     DB 'HelloWorld!$'
DATA    ENDS

CODE    SEGMENT USE16
ASSUME  CS:CODE,DS:DATA
BEG:    MOV AX,DATA
MOV     DS,AX
MOV     DX,OFFSET MSG
MOV     AH,9
INT     21H
CODE    ENDS
END     BEG
```

Using MASM command:
`masm h.asm` I have got the file h.obj. Then `link h.obj` I have got the h.exe file.

Now I want to obtain the .com file of the .exe file using command
`exe2bin h.exe`, but the result I received is:
File cannot be converted
What went wrong?

Comment: You can only have one segment in a COM file I guess.

Comment: @fuz Thanks, I changed deleted the data segment and it worked. But thus the program just does nothing. Can I still display hello world without data segment?

Comment: it has been decades, cant you use org 100h and go straight to .com with masm?

Comment: additional to `org 100` the first command (even before your data stuff) should be a `jmp BEG` to jump to the code (the "BEG" label's already there), and skip that data. the CPU would try to run the data stuff as code else

Comment: @BobHU Please show me your updated code.

Comment: @old-timer Thanks a lot! Now it's fixed!

Comment: @fuz https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.asm.x86/Pucf4nuTpg0  I find the answer here, for my new code, I'll answer it under this question. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program `exe2bin` requires that the .EXE file you're converting either has an entry point of 0000:0100 or no entry point at all. In the former case the the executable can't have any segment relocations, and the result is normally something that can be loaded by MS-DOS as a .COM file. In addition the .EXE file can't have a stack, and must have a load size 64K or less.

The direct reason why `exe2bin` is failing is because you have entry point of something like `0001:0000`, where the segment part is relative to the start of the executable and adjusted by the location in memory where MS-DOS loads the executable. (So for example if MS-DOS loads the executable at 1234:0000, then entry point is 1235:0000.) This isn't suitable for a .COM file since MS-DOS simply copies the .COM file into memory and jumps an offset 0100 in the segment. (So if MS-DOS loads the .COM file at 1234:0000, it jumps to 1234:0100).

Another problem with your executable is that even if it used the correct entry point it also a has a segment relocation. The `MOV AX, DATA` instruction references the segment `DATA`, and the value of `DATA` depends on where MS-DOS loads the executable. This requires a relocation in the executable so MS-DOS knows to modify the value with the correct segment value when it loads it.

To make an executable that will both work with `exe2bin` and produce a usable .COM file you need the following things:

1. An `ORG 100h` directive at the start of your program
2. A symbol defining the entry point placed after the `ORG 100h` directive so that it's located at offset 100h.
3. The entry point symbol must be supplied as the argument to `END` directive so it becomes the entry point.
4. There must be only one segment in which everything lives.
5. There must be nothing defined before the `ORG 100h` directive (otherwise it will be discarded by `exe2bin`).
6. The size of the executable, as loaded in memory must be less than 64K. This includes the 256 bytes taken up by the `ORG 100h` directive. In other words everything must live in the same 64K segment.

For example, you can turn your program into something can produce a working .COM file by rewriting it like this:

```
    .386
                                               ; Requirements implemented
CODE SEGMENT USE16                             ; 4. 
    ORG 100h                                   ; 1. 

    ASSUME  CS:CODE,DS:CODE,ES:CODE,SS:CODE    ; 4. 

BEG: MOV    DX,OFFSET MSG                      ; 2.
    MOV     AH,9
    INT     21H

    MOV     AX,4C00H ; exit the program
    INT     21H     

MSG DB 'HelloWorld!$'                          ; 4. 5.

CODE ENDS

    END     BEG                                ; 3.
```

Note that I've added an MS-DOS call to exit the program, otherwise your code would've continued to execute instructions after printing the message. In your original executable this would've been random uninitialized data, in the program above it would be the string `HelloWorld!$` as interpreted as x86 machine code.

As rcgldr posted you can skip the `exe2bin` step and have the linker produce a .COM file directly by using the `/TINY` option. The same rules given above for creating a .COM file apply when using this option.

Comment: That helps a lot. I actually changed my code as you posted before and it worked. I have another question. Why is it okay to define MSG at the bottom? We have used it before the definition. How does the OS work?  Also, can you explain why CS DS ES SS registers are all pointed to code block? What is the procedure of the OS compiling the code? Thanks anyway.

Comment: The assembler doesn't care where you define symbols. Otherwise it would be hard to jump forward to an instruction that comes later. When MS-DOS loads and executes a .COM file it sets CS, DS, ES and SS to the segment it loaded the file into. Since there's only one segment and everything in the program exists in that segment there's no other value to set the segment registers to. Note that one segment can be called anything, it doesn't have to be `CODE`. You could call it `FRED` and it would work just as well. The operating system doesn't compile the code.

Answer (score 1):

For real (16 bit) mode assembly, depending on the tool set, you may be able to use TINY model instead of using exe2bin.

Batch file for release build using Microsoft 16 bit toolset:

```
ml /c %1.asm
link /tiny %1.obj;
```

Batch file for debug (codeview) build:

```
ml /Zi /c %1.asm
link /CO /tiny %1.obj;
```

Example MSDOS / MASM (ML.EXE) 6.11 source code:

```
        .286
        .model  tiny,c
        .code
        org     0100h
main    proc    far
        lea     dx,msg0
        mov     ax,0900h                ;display msg
        int     21h
        mov     ax,04c00h               ;exit
        int     21h
msg0    db      'msdos tiny asm example',0dh,0ah,'$'
main    endp
        end     main
```

Microsoft 16 bit toolset and 16 bit programs will run in console mode on 32 bit versions of Windows. For 64 bit versions, use a virtual PC or perhaps DOSBOX.